# where to put $watch in directive in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

All:

Suppose I have a directive like:

```
app.directive("onedir", function(){
    return {
        restrict:"AE",
        scope: {
            data: "=data"
        },
        controller:function($scope){},
        link:function(scope, EL, attrs){}
    }
});
```

And I want to use $watch to monitor the data change inside the directive, should I put the $watch in the controller part or in the link part, like:

```
$scope.$watch("data", function(newdata, olddata){})
```

OR

```
scope.$watch("data", function(newdata, olddata){})
```

Comment: Do neither and let the data binding handle it automatically

Comment: scope: {  data: "=" }  <--  no need for extra variable names

Comment: monitor changes to do what? Controller and directive do different things so without knowing what the goal is nobody can help

Comment: @ExplosionPills Thanks, but could you show me how to do the auto binding in this directive without registering any watcher?

Comment: @DmitriAlgazin Thanks, this is just for example, actually the attr name is not same as the scope variable name.

Comment: The `=` has already set up a data binding.  If you are overwriting the value of `data` directly then the binding is broken. You can solve this by using a `dot`, typically can be handled via `controller as` syntax

Comment: @charlietfl Let's say we just want to print the data in console when data changed. But I need to use this directive to do that.

Comment: @ExplosionPills Thanks I got that part and that is why and how $watch can work. In my case, I need to do some extra jobs related to the changing of data, like UI and data processing, how can I do those without using a $watch

Comment: do it in controller... link should mostly be used to bind view events

Comment: @ExplosionPills still other cases for `$watch` not related to the bound scope item itself which may be what OP is after

Comment: @entre Thanks. But I am wondering most time, the pattern is data changing leads to UI changing, but in controller, I can not access the UI part, then how can I let the UI handling part know the data change if I do this in controller?

Comment: Kuan...Watch on directive since it is isolated instance. Each version of directive would have different `data` . If you had this being used in a repeater it would not be viable to use controller

Comment: @charlietfl Sorry, I did not quite catch this part, could you show me how to do this( by just showing me some sample directive code)

Comment: my bad..was thinking main controller...for logging should be fine in link. Code you have above is fine...just put some logging stements in the callback